# React native audio streaming

Tags: node.js, react-native, audio-streaming, audio-recording

I am building a react native app in which one client has to stream audio in real time to other clients over a node.js server. So while one client is talking into his microphone others are hearing what he's saying on their device. Could you please recommend some APIs for this sort of task. I was planning on using socket.io but other alternatives are more than welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may be interested, I solved my problem with WebRTC. It's an open-source project from Google that makes real-time communication a piece of cake.

Comment: with the help of react-native-webrtc, not by google? :-)

Comment: Of course, but react-native-webrtc is based on Google's tech :) anyway thanks for pointing that out.